# Angular RouterLink run in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Im trying to apply  to an specific RouterLink.

The Issue: i have a dynamic menu that is created from the database.

````
        <div class="sidebar-toggler">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="heading">
        <h3 class="uppercase">Menú</h3>
      </li>
      <!-- List of Main Category Elements -->
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let layout of layouts" appIsOpen (arrowUp)="callSomething($event)">
        <a class="nav-link">
          <i class="{{layout.icontag}}"></i>
          <span class="title">{{layout.categoryName}}</span>
          <span class="arrow" *ngIf="layout.items.length > 0" [ngClass]="{ 'open': arrowUp }"></span>
        </a>
        <!-- List of SubMenus -->
        <ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let subitem of layout.items">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a  routerLink="{{subitem.state}}"   target="_blank" class="nav-link" rel="noopener no referrer">
              <span class="title">{{subitem.moduleName}}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>```

 Here's the piece of code im touching:  <a  routerLink="{{subitem.state}}"   target="_blank" class="nav-link" rel="noopener no referrer">
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is only one way:

```
<a href="yourdomain.com/{{subitem.state}}" target="_blank" class="nav-link" rel="noopener no referrer">
```

Use interpolation for target :

```
[target] ="condition ? '_blank' : 'something'
```

Comment: I mean, the way im using it is working, but in in the wrong way.

Comment: What im trying to do is to filter de subitem.state and when the state is for example "Index/Consultas" apply the _blank

Comment: Great! Choose my answer ;) just keep in mind properties interpolation